# Fullwidth div inside a non-fullwidth

Tags: html, css, containers, fullscreen

I would create something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b29R9/3/). 
I have a container, with a 1024px width. Then I would create in the middle of the page a fullwidth-div, with for example an image. 
 In the example the yellow div should cover the blue one (that simulate my screen width ).
PS: I simplify the container, but think inside a wordpress wrapper where `.red` is the post and `.yellow` is the fullwidth-image. (Like [HERE](http://themeforest.net/item/alpine-wordpress-responsive-one-page-parallax/full_screen_preview/7191059) for example. I know that's made using the pages and not the posts ) 
HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="red">some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 
    <div class="yellow">some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
    </div>
    <div class="lime">some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .container{ background: blue; width: 400px;}
    .red {background:red; width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;}
    .yellow {background:yellow; width: 300px;}
    .lime {background:lime; width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: Use this code: http://jsfiddle.net/b29R9/6/

Answer (score 1):

You should close `.red` before you open `.yellow` otherwise `.red` will be the parent of `.yellow` and if you put `width:100%;` on `.yellow` it will take the `width:200px;` from `.red` instead of `.container`.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b29R9/4/).

Comment: check out new info, I explained better my issue :)

Comment: Not really, what are you trying to achieve with your example code?

Comment: I'm in wordpress, inside a post. I would add a colored-div/img that go fullwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Try out thinking different changing css parameter instead of using `background-color`. I have tested it with `:box-shadow` parameter:

```
.toggle {
      box-shadow: -10vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -28vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -42vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -30vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -46vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -15vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42;
      -webkit-box-shadow: -10vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -28vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -42vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -30vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -46vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -15vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42;
      -moz-box-shadow: -10vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -28vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -42vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -30vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -46vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42, -15vw 0px 0px 0px #0e1d42;
}
```

Take a look at live example: fullwidth blue section here: http://kreditka.testovi-site.pw

Regards,
Max